# Cocoa: Auto close a status menu

Tags: cocoa, nsmenu, nsstatusitem

I hava a status menu on the status bar, and I have some tasks running behind the scene. When one of task is done, assume at the time the menu is being showed (dropped down), I want to make the menu to be not in drop down mode (pretend doing a left click on the mouse on the menu icon) automatically. Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's there, but the name is a little bit counterintuitive: You want NSMenu's [`cancelTracking`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSMenu_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSMenu/cancelTracking).